# view docx document in iframe open particular page using office live embeded url

Tags: iframe

My code is:

```html
<iframe src='https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=http://calibre-ebook.com/downloads/demos/demo.docx#page=2' width='1366px' height='623px' frameborder='0'>
```

In this code i mentioned page open to 2. but is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The code is not working because the api use a https protocol and your server use http protocol, check the developer tools and you can view the error, i suggest to modify your code and change for this:

Check that and give a feedback if this alternative it worked for you